# Use of Worker Threads along with Main Thread will reduce the response delay or increase the work load in Java based Smart Devices?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, smartphone

Main Thread; initial application code is executed.
Worker Thread; time-consuming and background tasks are executed.

But Worker Threads along with Main Thread will reduce the response delay or increase the work load in Java based Smart Devices?

Answer (score 1):

In my Opinion, Use of the Work Thread along with the Main Thread will Increase the work load in Java Based Smart Devices:

Reason:

Work Thread is the Continuous Parallel Thread, that runs and accept messages or processing until the given loop time is explicitly complete (closed or terminated).
When a work Thread is created ,its wait for the task (process or message). When its gets task  (processor or message), its starts working on the given message or processor within given loop .
After the task is run(complete or terminates), it will again wait a new task. It will periodically check for the availability of task(process or message) every few milliseconds.
If we try to assign another task, while it is still busy with current task, then it will throw a exception “Already running task!”
Work Thread is fully responsibly to execute a task, it never release its given task without completing its given time or loop. Its also not allow another process to disturb.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will help you.

"Yes, Use of worker threads along with Main Thread will reduce the response delay, Threads allow utilization of multiprocessor architectures to a greater scale and efficiency.
Threads use very little resources of an operating system in which they are working. That is,
Threads do not need new address space, global data, program code or operating system resources.
Main thread, is responsible for everything that happens onscreen after application starting.
Responsiveness of your application UI that you do not block the UI thread. If you have operations to perform that are not instantaneous, you should make sure to do them in separate worker threads".